# QZ factorization in R

Tags: r

I am actually trying to perform a Generalized SCHUR decomposition in R. It looks like the package MATRIX only do the usuall SCHUR decomposition. I would like to know if there is any other package that does it. I read in some blog that we can actually call lapack function(DGGES.f) in R. I don't know how to do since DGGES depends on another external subroutine (SELCTG) to be defined by the user.

Your help will much appreciate.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not to use `Matrix` package, since it uses `LPACK dgees` subroutine?

Comment: Because dgees subroutine perform the normal SCHUR decomposition and the generalized version. From what I have read DGGES is more robust. I have also tried to see how it is done in Matlab. The matlab command QZ calls DGGES.f

Comment: I meant :Because dgees subroutine perform the normal SCHUR decomposition and NOT the generalized version. From what I have read DGGES is more robust. I have also tried to see how it is done in Matlab. The matlab command QZ calls DGGES.f